# Batch Scripting - dump msbuild output to a specific file instead of to the console window if successful?

Tags: msbuild, error-handling, batch-file, command, command-prompt

I'm not sure how to do this. I have a batch script file I am using to do multiple msbuild calls. I don't want the msbuild output to pollute my command window, but instead I want it to dump into a log file. I'm not sure how to do this, but here's my script so far:

```
@ECHO Building shared libraries ...

msbuild "SharedLibraries.sln"
:: Not sure how to catch an unsuccessful build here for my GOTO ERROR?
:: Copy dll files to specific location

@ECHO Building primary application...

msbuild "Myapp.sln"
:: Not sure how to catch an unsuccessful build here for my GOTO ERROR?

:ERROR
```

So, how do I:

1. Dump the msbuild output to a log file?
2. Catch unsuccessful builds and go to the error label?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adding the `/fileLogger` command line switch causes MSBuild to write the build output to  file *msbuild.log* in the current directory, while the `/noconsolelogger` switch causes MSBuild to no longer write to standard output. The filename can be set using the `/flp`switch as in the following example:

```
msbuild "SharedLibraries.sln" /nologo /noconsolelogger /fileLogger /flp:logfile=buildlog.txt
```

See [MSBuild Command Line Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx) for details.

Regarding your second question; MSBuild returns a non-zero exit code if the build failed, which can be processed as usual:

```
msbuild "SharedLibraries.sln" /nologo /noconsolelogger /fileLogger /flp:logfile=SharedLibraries.log
if not errorlevel 0 goto ERROR

msbuild "Myapp.sln" /nologo /noconsolelogger /fileLogger /flp:logfile=Myapp.txt
if not errorlevel 0 goto ERROR

:ERROR
```

Comment: And of course, good old output redirection works also to write the output to a file instead of stdout: `msbuild "SharedLibraries.sln" > SharedLibraries.log`